# Can't install spams on python 2.7 (Os: Fedora)

Tags: python, linux, pip, pyinstaller

I tried to install spams using PiP command but i get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-zI4__D/spams/setup.py", line 121, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(this_directory, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

So, i download the zipped file of spams, and i modified the setup.py file to prevent the encoding keyword problem, and when i install the library i get this error:

```
    warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/spams_wrap/spams_wrap.o -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib64 -lstdc++ -lblas -llapack -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_spams_wrap.so -fopenmp" failed with exit status 1
```

When i try "pip install spams==2.6.1", i get this error:

```
    error: Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_           FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4            -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG            -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong            --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOUR           CE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I. -Ispams/linalg -Ispams/prox -Ispams/decomp -Ispams/di           ctLearn -I/home/aabdelli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -           I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pytho           n2.7 -c spams_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/spams_wrap.o -DNDEBUG -DUS           E_BLAS_LIB -std=c++11 -fPIC -fopenmp -Wunused-variable -m64" failed with exit st           atus 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-           build-8cd3Ds/spams/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file           __).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-           OH2Naf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile -           -user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8cd3Ds/spams/
```

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported. Encoding is a very python-3 sort of thing. Consider switching to python 3.

Comment: Supported by what , didn't understand!! i can't switch to python3 because it's not my machine.
For the Encoding problem, i fixed it

Comment: Python devs no longer support it: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/. Numpy hasn't supported python 2 for a while as well. Set the #define the warning is telling you about to bypass. I suspect you'll have to do a lot more than that to get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

SPAMS' `setup.py` [imports `numpy`](https://gitlab.inria.fr/thoth/python-spams/-/blob/ecff15193b4ac448960ba8372068db6b31777245/setup.py#L11) before installing it so first you have to install `numpy`:

```
pip install numpy
```

SPAMS requires BLAS and LAPACK. You need to install the libraries for Fedora. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/BLAS_LAPACK. Try

```
yum install openblas lapack
```

Then go with SPAMS:

```
pip install spams==2.6.1
```

Comment: doesn't install also

Comment: Edit your question and show the text of the error.

Comment: I investigated a bit more and rewrote the answer.